# JOptionPane not showing when string is in wrong format?

Tags: java, string, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I have a text field set as a time, which rejects strings which are in invalid format. The correct format is HH:mm. When the user enters the incorrect format, I would like an error message to be displayed, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be showing the JOptionFrame. The weird thing is the JOptionPane shows fine when I take it out of the else statement, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

```
 if (timeString.getText()!= null)
 {
   System.out.println(timeString.getText());
 }
 else
 {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Incorrect format.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
```

Fixed it by doing timeString.getText().contains(":") eventhough it doesn't completely solve the issue.

Comment: You can write a code to check the format

Answer (score 0):

The JOptionPane will only show when the input is not `null`, not when the format is incorrect. Try entering no text in the JTextField, and see if it shows up then. Anyways, I don't see anything that checks if the format is incorrect, only if just nothing is entered.

Another option is using a formatted JSpinner for time, then no other input then time is possible. (I know this isn't an answer to your question, but I would really recommend this)

Comment: if I enter something like '12312312' then it doesn't print, so it must be null right?

Comment: Do you mean, it doesn't print the input to the console, or that the JOptionPane isn't showing?

Comment: It doesn't print the input to the console

Comment: It's ok I managed to do timeString.getText().contains(":"). It's a slight workaround but it works

Comment: The JTextField text won't necessarily be null unless you set it. Use the `isEmpty()` check.

Comment: You should really mention that in your question.